# How to move object from Amazon S3 to Glacier with Vault Locked enabled?

Tags: amazon-s3, data-integrity, amazon-glacier

I'm looking for a solution for moving Amazon S3 objects to Glacier with Vault Lock enabled (like described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/glacier-vault-lock/). I'd like to use Amazon built in tools for that (lifecycle management or some other) if possible.

I cannot find any instructions or options to do that. S3 seems to only allow moving object to Glacier storage class. But that does not provide data integrity nor defends against data loss.

I know I could do it with a program. It would download S3 object and move it to Glacier through their respective REST API's. This approach seems too complicated for this simple task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Picture it this way:

- Glacier is a service of AWS.
- S3 is a service of AWS.
- But S3 is also a *customer* of the Glacier service.

When you migrate an object in S3 to the Glacier storage class, S3 stores the object in Glacier... using an AWS account that is owned by S3.

Those objects in S3 that use the `GLACIER` storage class aren't in "your" Glacier vaults, they're in vaults owned by S3.

This is consistent with the externally-observable evidence:

- You can't see these S3 objects in vaults from the Glacier console.
- You don't have to give S3 any IAM permissions to access Glacier (by contrast, you *do* have to give S3 permission to publish event notifications to SQS, SNS, or Lambda)
- Glacier doesn't bill you for Glacier storage class objects -- S3 does.

In that light, what you are trying to accomplish is completely different.  You want to store some archives in *your* Glacier vault, with *your* policy, and that content currently just "happens to be" stored in S3 at the moment.

Downloading from S3 and then uploading to Glacier is the solution.

> But that does not provide data integrity nor defends against data loss.

The integrity of the payload can be assured when uploading to Glacier because the tree hash algorithm effectively prevents corrupt uploads.

Downloading from S3, unless the object is stored with [SSE-C](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html), the ETag is the MD5 hash of the stored object if single-part upload is used, or is the hex-encoded MD5 hash of the concatenated binary-encoded MD5 hashes of the parts, followed by `-` and the number of parts.  Ideally, when uploading to S3, you'd store a better hash (e.g. sha256) in the object metadata, e.g. `x-amz-meta-content-sha256`.

Defense against data loss -- yes, Glacier does offer more functionality, here, but S3 is not entirely without capability here: bucket policies with a matching `DENY` action will always override *any* conflicting `ALLOW` action, whether it is in the bucket policy or any other IAM policy (e.g. role, user).

Comment: Your explanation is good, explains well what is going on under the hood.

The comment "But that does not provide data integrity nor defends against data loss." was about S3 Glacier storage class. I agree that I can safely download the object from S3 and upload to my Glacier Vault.

I was just hoping that Amazon has a solution for this case.

Comment: @JoosepSimm a solution for which case, exactly?  Object Versioning in S3 offers protection against accidental overwrite/delete. S3 bucket policies can protect against deliberate overwrites.  S3 validates `Content-MD5` and/or `x-amz-content-sha255` on uploads to ensure an upload is rejected, not stored, if the upload is not transferred intact. Once stored in S3, in any storage class, objects and their metadata (including the timestamp) are immutable. The S3 console *appears* to allow metadata edits, but not really -- this actually makes a new copy of the existing object, with a new timestamp.

Comment: I need protection from deliberate deletion of files - for example when the master  account is taken over by a hostile party. As I understand, it's possible to delete the old versions from S3. If it's protected by security policy, then it's possible to change the policy and then delete the old versions.
The Vault Lock in Glacier has this kind of protection.

Comment: If the master (root) account is compromised, you're right... essentially everything is at risk except locked vaults.  Sort of unrelated, I have a sync process from S3 to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) that replicates everything in S3 to GCS.  The credentials that enable this are configured and stored in such a way that compromising one system could reveal my data to you, but to wipe me out entirely (shudder), you'd have to compromise both platforms.  Regarding root compromise, see also https://alestic.com/2014/09/aws-root-password/.